# Как выдать более совпадающий класс по переменным

Tags: python, python-3.x

знатоки питона, у меня есть два класса:

```py
class bobik:
    name = "Bobik"
    age = 8
    sex = 1



class tuzik:
    name ="Tuzik"
    age = 9
    sex = 2
```

Я хочу сделать так:
Пользователь ввод данные "питомца" , а программа должна выдать более подходящий класс
Но к сожалению, я не знаю как это сделать, помогите мне пожалуйста

Comment: какие данные?..

Comment: Вам бы дать побольше описания логики. На данный момент все написанное можно объеденить в один класс и создать два объекта. А уже объекты сравнивать

Comment: Да, класс тут должен быть один `Dog`. А вот что такое "более подходящий" - потрудитесь объяснить, это вопрос не такой уж и простой на самом деле. Точное совпадение характеристик - это понятный вариант. А вот если не точное совпадение, то мера похожести - это нетривиальный вопрос.